# How to make the background image stick to the bottom of browser

Tags: html, css, wordpress, footer, sticky-footer

I would like to have the footer image of my website stick to the bottom of the browser when the page content is short.
[image: Footer Image should stick to bottom of browser]

The CSS code I have for that image is:

```
#site-container {width:100%; background:url(.../site-bg-foot.jpg) no-repeat left bottom;}
```

and it works perfectly for the pages where the content is longer.

I have tried using code from some tutorials out there but I have not been able to get the results I want. Is there a property I can add to that line of code to make the image stay at the bottom?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
```

For the footer in your CSS

I'd also recommend you [read this article](http://www.cssreset.com/how-to-keep-footer-at-bottom-of-page-with-css/) in case the above isnt quite your flavour, broadly speaking:

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div id="content"></div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
html,
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
#wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
#header {
    padding:10px;
    background:#5ee;
}
#content {
    padding:10px;
    padding-bottom:80px;   /* Height of the footer element */
}
#footer {
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    background:#ee5;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but the footer image now appears at the bottom of the browser and on TOP of the content. It should appear after the content ends

Comment: Well, I found the problem!!.. i had some redundant code in my css, I fixed it and now it works perfectly! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rileychuggins/pk53E/) to see what can solve your problem.

First I added `position:fixed;` and `bottom:0;` to the `.footer` div class.

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
<p>Praesent aliquam varius dolor.</p>
</div>

<div class="footer">Curabitur interdum, lorem quis feugiat interdum.
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin:0;
}
.content {
    width: 100%;    
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
```